# Rendering hexagons in d3.js in the wordmap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Rendering hexagons in d3.js in the wordmap**

I need to render hexagons in a wordmap I have this code that renders circles but I want to render polygons and use a function that converts the coordinates to points

```
<g className="markers">
    {
      position.map((city, i) => (
        <circle
          key={ `marker-${i}` }
          cx={ projection(city.coordinates)[0] }
          cy={ projection(city.coordinates)[1] }
          r={ city.population / 3000000 }
          fill={ '#FFF8F' }
          stroke="#FFFFF"
          class="marker"
          strokeWidth={ 0.5 }

          >
          
       </circle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hexagonPoints` function.

To apply coordinates to hexagons, use:

```
.attr('transform', `translate(${projection(city.coordinates)[0]},${ projection(city.coordinates)[1]})`);
```

```js
const hexagonPoints = (radius) => {
  const halfWidth = radius * Math.sqrt(3) / 2;
  return `
    0,${-radius}
    ${halfWidth},${-radius / 2}
    ${halfWidth},${radius / 2}
    0,${radius}
    ${-halfWidth},${radius / 2}
    ${-halfWidth},${-radius / 2}`;
};

 const svg = d3.select('svg');

 svg.append('polygon')
  .attr('points', hexagonPoints(20))
  .attr('transform', 'translate(50,70)')
  .style('stroke', 'red')
  .style('fill', 'none');

svg.append('polygon')
  .attr('points', hexagonPoints(30))
  .attr('transform', 'translate(80,110)')
  .style('stroke', 'green')
  .style('fill', 'none');

svg.append('polygon')
  .attr('points', hexagonPoints(40))
  .attr('transform', 'translate(110,50)')
  .style('stroke', 'blue')
  .style('fill', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg/>
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks i can draw the hexsgon now. But i need convert cordinates for draw in the word map.

Comment: What is word map? The World Map?

Comment: @MaikonWeberCarvalho I'm happy to help. Please mark my answer as correct